# Ajax Success method not updating the html content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My Requirement is to call ajax and after either success or failure i have to add text message to my html.Ajax call is happening fine.Response is also coming fine.But updating the html content is not happening.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({      
    type:'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url:'myurlhere',
    success: function(response){
           // errorHtml is updating here correctly
           var errorHtml = $('<div />').append(response[0]).html();
           $("#Error").html(errorHtml); 
    }, 
    error: function(e){
        var errorHtml = $('<div />').append('error').html();
        $('#Error').html(errorHtml); 
    }
});
```

My html. This is present inside a table.

```
<td>
    <span  id="Error" style="alight:left">
</td>
```

**Note:**
1) My response is json list
2) I have tried

```
var errorHtml = '<div>'+response[0]+'</div>';
```

also. But it is not updating.

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: And what is the `response`?

Comment: You say your response is json? So do you want to display the raw json on your page? Or do you want to convert it to a ul - li list in html? Please also show a sample of your result.

Comment: I just wannt to show the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `div` wrapper around the content, since you're already inside a `<span>` inside a `<td>`.

Assuming that `response[0]` really does contain valid data, just put the content directly into the error span:

```
$('#Error').html(response[0]);
```

Do be sure that there's only one element with the ID `Error` on your page, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
It was happening because the td inside which span was present is hidden.So it is updating the content in js but it is not updating html because of this.Thanks for responses.I was conditionally hiding the td.That was issue.When i moved the span to some other portion it started working fine.
Hope this might help for others